# the nn.init.normal_ result change after just adding other parameter

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, init

I create a model and initialize the parameter with nn.init.normal_, however, the weight change after I add another Parameter(no other operation including initalization) .
The code is here, uncomment to get another case.

```
def __init__(self):
        self.tc_h = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Linear(512, 1024),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        )
        self.tg_h = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Linear(512, 1024),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        )
        self.vc_h = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Linear(512, 1024),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        )
        self.vg_h = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Linear(512, 1024),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        )

        #self.tc_Q = torch.nn.Linear(512, 512)
        #self.vc_Q = torch.nn.Linear(512, 512)
        #self.tg_Q = torch.nn.Linear(512, 512)
        #self.vg_Q = torch.nn.Linear(512, 512)

        for layer in [
            self.tc_h, self.tg_h, self.vc_h, self.vg_h,
            #self.tc_Q, self.tg_Q, self.vc_Q, self.vg_Q,
        ]: 
            for name, param in layer.named_parameters():
                if name.endswith('weight'):
                    nn.init.normal_(param, std=1024 ** -0.5)
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"the weight changes after I add another parameter"*?

Comment: I have set the random seed, but the weight of this parameter is different after adding another layer.

Comment: How did you set the random seed? Did you add this new layer before that one?

Comment: no, I set the random seed before initialize the model, both layer are defined in the __init__ func.

Comment: *Did you add this new layer before that one?*

Comment: no, both layers are added in the __init__ func, and the weight is consistent as I delete the row ```torch.nn.Linear(512, 512)```

Comment: This is quite unclear can you show exactly how you are defining your code in both cases?

Comment: the code is below.

Comment: So the commented lines were the ones you added after the initial test, right?

Comment: yes, I uncomment these lines and the weight of tc_h after nn.init.normal_ changes

Comment: It is supposed to change since you are applying the normal init on their weights. Do you mean that you are not able to reproduce those initialization while setting a seed beforehand?

Comment: I mean I can reproduce the result in both cases(comment and uncomment these lines), but the results(weight of tc_h) of the two cases are different.